# Webpage screen capture using go

Tags: go, phantomjs

I'm porting a screen capture module from Node.Js to Go. The existing module was used to screen capture a webpage. The existing module used [node-phantom](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node) library written on top of phantomjs. Is there a similar alternative available for go? Or is there any alternative better approach to do so?

There seems to exist one [lightweight wrapper](https://github.com/urturn/go-phantomjs/), but it doesn't expose the methods which the node library does.

This is more of a explorative question. We just need some information before we decide to invest time in it.

Comment: Not sure how easy it is, but it's possible using [webdriver](https://github.com/fedesog/webdriver) [see also](https://gowalker.org/github.com/fedesog/webdriver#Session_Screenshot)

Comment: That's an interesting alternative. How does it comparable to selenium webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about any GO package , but you can do it using [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) in your Golang code..

Comment: Thanks. I believe this package makes an assumption of the source code being available to the developer, which might not always be the case